# BIOS Black Screen but not on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios

I've just built my first PC, and tried testing it out :).

After making sure everything was plugged in, I turned it on. All the fans started (including my graphics card's fans). When I tried to go to the BIOS Setup by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the start screen, I received a black screen. The fans were still running, but nothing showed up.

So, I turned the PC off and connected an external hard drive that has (bootable) Ubuntu installed on it. This time, after the initial load screen (that displays the Motherboard's name), the GRUB screen came up. I booted into Ubuntu, and received an error that my hard drive (assuming my internal hard drive --- not the Ubuntu one) was not configured (or something of the sort). I believe this is because I do not have any partitions or file system on the hard drive.

I pressed <kbd>S</kbd> to not mount it,
and after a minute or so of the black screen, the normal Ubuntu interface displayed.

Everything seemed to work fine, and the all of the installed memory displayed, as well as the driver for the graphics card.

So, I know my graphics card is working. Why isn't the BIOS screen working? I haven't run the CD that I received with the motherboard (I still have to buy an optical drive for my PC), so could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the BIOS using the CD you got. Buy a new cd drive or install software from manufacturer website

Comment: The CD's title is "Gigabyte AMD 9/8/7 Series Utilities" --- is that the BIOS installer?

Comment: Also, I thought BIOS came with the motherboard?